# no puedo conectarme a la base de datos desde spring boot

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot

Estooy probando por primera vez un proyecto de spring boot, con conexion a una base de datos en sql server . el archivo application proerties tiene lo siguiente:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.3:1433;databaseName=guardia;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=SaD1212*
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

cuando ejecuto el codigo me da el siguiente error:
ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:e653d388-c1f6-4d3f-8368-b084924c6926

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando el `trusted connection` al final de tu connection string.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.3:1433;databaseName=guardia;trusted_connection=True;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo que me funcionó es la siguiente cadena de conexion:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.3:1433;databaseName=guardia;;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;

Comment: Buenísimo, depende de la version de .net que uses y el modo de autenticarte con la base de datos va variando el connection string, es probar y probar hasta encontrar la que sirva jaja!